# how can I fix the "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop." issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to loop through an object and add up the numbers in there.

```
  const [cartCount, setCartCount] = useState(0)

  for (let i = 1; i <= Object.keys(cartItems).length; i++) { //cartItems is the object
     setCartCount(cartCount + cartItems[i])
  }
```

but any attempt to update the state throws me the too many renders error. So how can I fix this?

Comment: Like the error says, react reduces the amount of rerenders in a component. what is the value of `cartItems` ?

Comment: @unhackit it's got a list of ids and a count property (if that's what you call it) like 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 5.... and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply initialize your state with your value.

```js
const initialCount = Object.values(cartItems).reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0)

const [cartCount, setCartCount] = useState(initialCount)
```

But if you just need to have it stored once, you don't even need a state, you can keep your `const`

Comment: it worked great thanks @dbuchet !
But as fate would have it, I ran into another problem. I realized I need the summed variable in my navbar component so I tried to send it with the useContext hook but it becomes undefined when it receives it. any fixes for this? (also I have moved the code to a context provider file I made which is where the object comes form)

Comment: I think would be best to open a new question on SO with your updated code :)

Answer (score 1):

the reason of error is that you re-render the state in a loop.
lets mutate your data then update state.

```
  const [cartCount, setCartCount] = useState(0)

  const handle = ()=>{
  let newCount = cartCount;

  for (let i = 1; i <= Object.keys(cartItems).length; i++) { 
  
  newCount = cartCount + cartItems[i];
 }
 setCartCount(newCount)
 }
```

Comment: although this fixes it, cartCount is not updated unless the handle function is called. And when it is, the issue comes back.

Comment: no , in this approach you update the state just once when your loop complete.try this you shouden,t take error

Comment: you must make your data in your loop, when your data be ready,update the state just once

Comment: Well it's still not working because like i said if i don' call the handle function, nothing happens to the state, and if I do call it: like so (handle()) the render issue returns. (It does not immediately show up tho only when i run the handle function this time )

Comment: add your handle function to useEffect hook to just run when your app render

Comment: useEffect(()=>{ yourHandleFunction },[])

Comment: i think you wanna to calculate data when your app load.true? or you calculate data when an action trigger? like onclick

Comment: yes on load but thanks anyway since I already found an answer but run into another problem feel free to find a fix for that. I've detailed the issue on the accepted answer's comments.